# Can I Have 2 Different Rest Poses For My Rig?

Tags: rigging, armature, shape-keys, pose-mode

I am making a Minecraft character, and I want it to have an option to have 2 different size options for the eyes.  This means that the rig would have to change its rest pose to accommodate for the changes.

Is there a way I can have 2 different rest poses so I can change the settings for the eye size, without having to make 2 separate rigs?

Comment: No, but you can have 1) a pose library, now a pose Asset in blender 3.x, where one rig is an adjustment from the rest.  Or 2) you have two different armatures, and you choose which armature is applied to your (common) mesh in a scene -- to save on file size.

Comment: thx, I'll look into that